# Speech synthesis on IOS devices via browser

Tags: javascript, ios, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am trying to run speechsynthesis TTS in a browser on IOS.
I understand there is some issue where IOS blocks TTS is called programatically, but I can't seem to get it to run there when a direct on click to a button. (it works on non-IOS devices)

```
<a onclick="PlayTTS()">Play</a>

<script>

function PlayTTS()
{
    var audio=new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();                   
    audio.text="Hello from the iPad";                       
    speechSynthesis.speak(audio);                           
}
```